# Using async/await with firebase firestore to download images

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function to list all images below

I need to wait until this function is completely finished before performing another action.

The problem is that I didn't understand the async /await in this case.

```
function listAllImages() {
  listRef.listAll()
  .then((res) => {

      res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {});
      res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {

          // Get the download URL
          itemRef.getDownloadURL()
              .then((url) => {
                  container.innerHTML += `<img src="${url}"/>`
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                  switch (error.code) {
                      case 'storage/object-not-found':
                          break;
                      case 'storage/unauthorized':
                          break;
                      case 'storage/canceled':
                          break;

                      case 'storage/unknown':
                          break;
                  }
              });

      });
  }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Uh-oh, an error occurred!")
  });
}
```

Comment: What does "I didn't understand the async / await in this case" mean? Are you getting some specific error? What is the actual problem?

Comment: *I need to wait until this function is completely finished..*, What function is *this* function?

Comment: I need to wait for all these pictures to be added to the container before executing another function. The problem is that to get the urls from firebase, this process is done asynchronously. I don't know if I was clear.

Comment: @Nemanja The OP is using trying to use Promises started from inside a for loop and wait for all of them to resolve before the Promise that is returned by `listAllImages()` resolves which could be done using `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you be a little more precise it's new for me the asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this but I'm not sure why a loop is ran on `req.prefixes`.

```
async function listAllImages() {
    const res = await listRef.listAll()
    // res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => { });

    const requests = res.items.map(itemRef => itemRef.getDownloadURL())
    const urls = await Promise.all(requests)

    urls.forEach((url) => {
        container.innerHTML += `<img src="${url}"/>`
    })
}

listAllImages().then(() => {
  console.log("All images listed")
}).catch((e) => console.log(e))
```